# How to read the python string formatting grammar?

Tags: python, string-formatting

The python documentation has information on the grammar of [formatting strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), however I can't seem to find information on how to read the table defining the grammar for the replacement field.

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s" | "a"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

There's also a similar table in the [format specification section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

I understand portions of the table, like the `::=` separates the definiendum and definien, characters inside quotes are literals, and the `|` means "or", but the rest of the table escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of formatting is what's known as Backus-Naur Form. [More information found on BNF here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) Basically, BNF is a set of derivation rules.

Defining the symbols:

- Anything other than the meta symbols ::=, |, and class names in closed in <,> are symbols of the language being defined (e.g. This Python example)
- The meta symbols ::= is to be interpreted as "is defined as"
- The | is used to separate alternative definitions and is interpreted as "or"
- The meta symbols <,> are delimiters enclosing a class name.

A little bit of dissecting this example to get you started:

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
```

`replacement_field` consists of an optional `field_name`, optional `conversion` and optional `format_spec`. The brackets ( the [ and ]'s ) indicate *optional parameters*.

If you do pass in `field_name` to `replacement_field`, it consists of an `arg_name` function in which you pass `attribute_name` *or* `element_index`. Note `element_index` is mandatory because the brackets are in quotation marks, and thus escaping BNF form for optional.